# Should i host my ajax enabled wcf service?

Tags: ajax, wcf, production-environment

My web application uses an ajax enabled wcf service and everything is fine as of now...

But what about when i move my application to production server.... Should i host my ajax enabled wcf service?... Any suggestion from anyone who had experience in hosting an ajax enabled wcf service...

Comment: Why would you not host it on your production environment?

Comment: @keith my question should i host or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By AJAX enabled WCF service I suppose you mean a WCF service that exposes an endpoint using `webHttpBinding` which is JSON encoding some data. As long as your AJAX enabled web service is hosted on the same domain and sub-domain as the application consuming it you should be fine.

Comment: @Darin i use it only within my domain.... So there wont be a problem am i right..

Comment: **Subdomain** should be the same as well.